# How to handle proxy authentication in mozilla firefox using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Mozilla firefox and when the browser is open with given URL,it has a proxy authentication that asking username and password..Is there any solution to remove that?

here's my code:

```
public class SimpleSelenium {

    WebDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SimpleSelenium ss = new SimpleSelenium();
        ss.openBrowser();
        ss.getPage();
        ss.quitPage();
    }

    private void openBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    }

    private void quitPage() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    private void getPage() {
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");        
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a proxy with username and password I can test?

Comment: nothing change tarun I used this driver.get("http://balindojmb:Password0001@www.google.com");

Comment: The url you tried is wrong as such. It should be `driver.get("http://balindojmb:Password0829@www.google.com")`. I have my doubts that it would work, but you can still give it a shot

Comment: nothing changed tarun

Comment: the proxy is pop up again

Comment: u will hack my computer I will not give that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155227/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-pablo-job).

Comment: @tarun u give same solution as I am given

Comment: @iamsankalp89, i just corrected the url he was browsing. I didn't suggest a solution. I just pointed out what was wrong with the trial he did. Nothing personal against anyone here, just trying to help in anyway I can

Comment: I am not personal dear. I am just saying Please provide a solution @PabloJob.

Answer (score 0):

If it is browser authentication you can use;

this solution is for c#
for java most of the time you need to lower case the letter :)

```
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("username", "password");
alert.Accept();
```